# How to reduce conversion/compression time in FFmpeg and How to merge command?

Tags: android, video, command-line, ffmpeg

I want to reduce time taken to create new video after adding text in original video using **FFmpeg** 
I had tried to search and I found this code given below for reducing time.

```
 -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -strict experimental -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 24 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b 36000k -s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 /sdcard/videokit/out3.mp4
```

Now, I want to add text in video and it is done in **FFmpeg**, by this command and its 100% working.

```
  String[] addTextCommand = {
            "-i",
            "" + realFilePath,
            "-vf",
            "drawtext=fontsize=50:fontfile=/storage/emulated/0/Download/Cerbetica-regular.ttf:fontcolor=red:text='"
                    + strText +
                    "':x=0:y=0: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=10: x=0: y=(h-text_h)/2",
            "-strict",
            "-2",
            outputFilePath};
```

Now my problem is how do I merge this two code and make one single command to make an edited video and also take less time to create a new video. In this, I have tried this command but it's not working.

```
   String[] addTextCommand = {
            "-i",
            "" + realVideoPath,
            "-vf",
            "-c:v", "libx264",
            "-preset", "ultrafast",
            "-crf", "24",
            "-acodec", "aac",
            "-ar", "44100",
            "-ac", "2",
            "-b", "36000k",
            "-s", "1280x720",
            "-aspect", "16:9",
            "-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0",
            "drawtext=fontsize=50:fontfile=/storage/emulated/0/Download/Cerbetica-regular.ttf:fontcolor=red:text='"
                    + strText +
                    "':x=0:y=0: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=10: x=0: y=(h-text_h)/2",
            "-strict",
            "-2",
            outputFilePath};
```

If anyone has an idea how to make command of **FFmpeg** please describe it and explain how to use it.

Using command of @Mulvya I got this in the console.

```
     D/MainActivity: FAILED with output : WARNING: linker: /data/user/0/com.inheritx.videoprocessing/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
                   ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                     built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                     configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/i686-linux-android- --arch=x86 --cpu=i686 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/x86 --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -march=i686' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                     libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                     libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                     libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                     libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                     libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                     libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                     libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                     libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                   Unrecognized option '2'.
                   Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -i
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg /storage/emulated/0/Download/spacetestSMALL_512kb.mp4
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -vf
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg drawtext=fontsize=50:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=red:text='Hello':x=0:y=0: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=10: x=0: y=(h-text_h)/2
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -c:v
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg libx264
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -preset
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg ultrafast
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -crf
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg 24
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -acodec
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg aac
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -ar
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg 44100
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -s
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg 1280x720
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -aspect
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg 16:9
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -strict
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg -2
   D/MainActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg /storage/emulated/0/Movies/add_text25.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   String[] addTextCommand = {
            "-i",
            "" + realVideoPath,
            "-vf",
            "drawtext=fontsize=50:fontfile=/storage/emulated/0/Download/Cerbetica-regular.ttf:fontcolor=red:text='"
                    + strText +
                    "':x=0:y=0: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=10: x=0: y=(h-text_h)/2",
            "-c:v", "libx264",
            "-preset", "ultrafast",
            "-crf", "24",
            "-acodec", "aac",
            "-ar", "44100",
            "-ac", "2",
            "-s", "1280x720",
            "-aspect", "16:9",
            "-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0",
            "-strict",
            "-2",
            outputFilePath};
```

The drawtext string is an argument for the video filter option, but you had separated them.

Comment: By using your command I got this error - "Unrecognized option '2'. Error splitting the argument list: Option not found"

Comment: Show the console output.

Comment: The loglevel's not high enough. Add `-report`. Share the logfile that's created.

Comment: I need to see the actual string passed o. This is all ffmpeg sees: `ffmpeg [Ljava.lang.String;@1a4d20f`

Comment: "Hello" this is actual string i am adding

Comment: FFmpeg command string, not text string. We'll have to do this via elimination. Remove `"-ac", "2",` and check.